# Sharing price updates in real time

Tags: vba, excel

I've been putting together this small program to pull real time share prices from Google Finance based on a user-inputted company code. However, the first function I've defined (at the top) only works for AAPL, not any other company codes, and the second function (to find the price) has an object defined error in line 32. I'm quite new to VBA (only been using it for 4 days). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
Function ExtractCID(fcid As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, iCount As Integer
    Dim sText As String
    Dim lNum As String

    sText = fcid

    For iCount = Len(sText) To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(sText, iCount, 1)) Then
            i = i + 1
            lNum = Mid(sText, iCount, 1) & lNum
        End If

        If i = 1 Then lNum = CInt(Mid(lNum, 1, 1))
    Next iCount

    ExtractCID = CInt(lNum)
End Function

Public Function TakePrice(fpri As String) As Single
    Dim s As String, i As Integer
    Dim fprice As String
    fprice = fpri

    For i = 1 To Len(fprice)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(fprice, i, 1)) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    s = Mid(fprice, i, InStr(fprice, "</") - 1)
    TakePrice = Convert.ToSingle(s)
End Function

Sub Shares()
    Dim EPIC As String
    Dim fprice As String
    Dim sPrice As Single
    Dim pPrice As Single
    Dim Shares As Integer
    Dim Change As Single
    Dim Cost As Single
    Dim MktVl As Single
    Dim LG As Single
    Dim L As Single
    Dim url As String
    Dim StartNumber As Integer
    Dim EndNumber As Integer
    Dim x As String
    Dim cid As Integer
    Dim fcid As String

    EndNumber = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))
    For StartNumber = 2 To EndNumber
        Sheet2.Cells(StartNumber, 1).Activate
        EPIC = ActiveCell.Value
         url = "http://www.google.com/finance?q=" & EPIC
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        x = .ResponseText
    End With
    fcid = (Mid(x, InStr(1, x, "cid="), 15))
    cid = ExtractCID(fcid)
    Range("B4").Value = cid
    fprice = Mid(x, InStr(1, x, cid & "_l") + Len(cid) + 3, 15)
    sPrice = TakePrice(fprice)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = sPrice
    pPrice = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    Shares = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    Cost = pPrice * Shares
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Cost
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ((sPrice - pPrice) / pPrice) * 100
    MktVl = sPrice * Shares
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = MktVl
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = MktVl - Cost
    L = ((MktVl - Cost) / Cost) * 100
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = L
    If L < 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
    Next StartNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: For your 2nd error, change `Convert.ToSingle(s)` to `csng(s)`. What are some of the other codes on your sheet? Is AAPL the first one?

Comment: MSFT seems to have a CID of 358464 - when you try to convert this to an Integer in your first function you will get an overflow error. Setting the the function's type to Long should resolve this. Is this your problem -i.e. that the codes you are choosing have CID values beyond 32768 (maximum value for an Integer).

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Using Double and Long instead of Single and Integer sorted it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `TakePrice` function change the line:

```
s = Mid(fprice, i, InStr(fprice, "</") - 1)
```

to

```
s = Mid(fprice, i, InStr(fprice, "</") - i)
```

Then here's a cleaned-up version of the main Sub. As mentioned in the comments, it changes `Convert.ToSingle(s)` to `CSng(s)`, as the former won't compile in VBA.

Notice that I defined a worksheet to use for all operations. You had specified `Sheet2` in some lines, but left `Cells` and `Ranges` unqualified in others. This also eliminates references to `ActiveCell`, and instead uses your For loop index, which is a better practice.

I commented out your `'.Range("B4").Value = cid` line - not sure what you intended there, but you'd want to make it relative like all the other lines if you actually use it. I also removed two unused variables - seems like you've got plenty, just with those being used :).

I also fixed your LastRow calculation.

Finally I moved the CreateObject outside the loop. I think it works fine that way:

```
Sub Shares()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim objMsxm12 As Object
Dim EPIC As String
Dim fprice As String
Dim sPrice As Single
Dim pPrice As Single
Dim Shares As Integer
Dim Cost As Single
Dim MktVl As Single
Dim L As Single
Dim url As String
Dim StartNumber As Integer
Dim EndNumber As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim cid As Integer
Dim fcid As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set objMsxm12 = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
With ws
    EndNumber = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For StartNumber = 2 To EndNumber
        With .Cells(StartNumber, 1)
            EPIC = .Value
            url = "http://www.google.com/finance?q=" & EPIC
            With objMsxm12
                .Open "GET", url, False
                .send
                x = .ResponseText
            End With
            fcid = (Mid(x, InStr(1, x, "cid="), 15))
            cid = ExtractCID(fcid)
            '.Range("B4").Value = cid
            fprice = Mid(x, InStr(1, x, cid & "_l") + Len(cid) + 3, 15)
            sPrice = TakePrice(fprice)
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = sPrice
            pPrice = .Offset(0, 2).Value
            Shares = .Offset(0, 3).Value
            Cost = pPrice * Shares
            .Offset(0, 4).Value = Cost
            .Offset(0, 5).Value = ((sPrice - pPrice) / pPrice) * 100
            MktVl = sPrice * Shares
            .Offset(0, 6).Value = MktVl
            .Offset(0, 7).Value = MktVl - Cost
            L = ((MktVl - Cost) / Cost) * 100
            .Offset(0, 8).Value = L
            If L < 0 Then
                .Offset(0, 8).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                .Offset(0, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
        End With
    Next StartNumber
End With
Set objMsxm12 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Finally, I'd change all the `Single` declarations to `Double` and the `Integers` to `Longs`. Those are the native types, and they'll actually perform as well or better.